# How to add options to bloomberg bdh query using api in python

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I have the following excel-formula:

`=@BDH("TSLA US Equity";"IVOL_Delta";start_date;end_date;IVOL_MATURITY=Maturity_90D;IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL=DELTA_LVL_25;IVOL_DELTA_PUT_OR_CALL=IVOL_CALL;days=a;Sort=D;cols=2;rows=1826)`.

Where the security is TSLA US Equity, the field is IVOL_Delta, start date and end dates speaks for itself, and the options is the remaining.

It works just fine in Excel.

I would like to use the API for python instead, but I don't know how to translate the options to a feasible input, I have tried both as dictionary and as list (could have messed something up though).

I tried the following code without luck (it works if the if I delete the dict and "options=opt" lines):

```
import pandas
from blp import blp

bquery = blp.BlpQuery().start()

opt = {"IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL":"DELTA_LVL_25"}

bquery.bdh(
    ["TSLA US Equity"],
    ["PX_LAST","IVOL_Delta","VOLUME_TOTAL_CALL"],#,"OPT_DELTA_MID_RT"
    start_date="20210801",
    end_date="20210819",
    options = opt,
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does 'OPT_DELTA_MID_RT" do? It is not in your BDH call ...

Comment: It was another field I tried, but I didn't need the output, it was just to test. Sorry if it caused confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output in Excel of this formula:

`=BDH("TSLA US Equity","PX_LAST,IVOL_Delta,VOLUME_TOTAL_CALL",D2,D3,"IVOL_MATURITY","Maturity_90D","IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL","DELTA_LVL_25","IVOL_DELTA_PUT_OR_CALL","IVOL_CALL")`

is:

[image]

You can get the same data using the `xbbg` package. There are plenty of wrappers for Bloomberg in Python, but this one is my personal favourite (`pip install xbbg`)

```
from xbbg import blp
from datetime import datetime

df = blp.bdh('TSLA US Equity',['PX_LAST','IVOL_Delta','VOLUME_TOTAL_CALL'],datetime(2021,8,1),datetime(2021,8,19),
                 IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL='DELTA_LVL_25',
                 IVOL_MATURITY='MATURITY_90D',
                 IVOL_DELTA_PUT_OR_CALL='IVOL_CALL')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
           TSLA US Equity                             
                  PX_LAST IVOL_Delta VOLUME_TOTAL_CALL
2021-08-02       709.6700    50.4803         1049494.0
2021-08-03       709.7400    50.3468          678750.0
2021-08-04       710.9200    50.0790          661374.0
2021-08-05       714.6300    49.7532          551532.0
2021-08-06       699.1000    47.7234          918211.0
2021-08-09       713.7600    47.6382          469777.0
2021-08-10       709.9900    46.8017          448640.0
2021-08-11       707.8200    46.3517          431084.0
2021-08-12       722.2500    46.7595          882608.0
2021-08-13       717.1700    47.3414         1028457.0
2021-08-16       686.1700    48.3680          639570.0
2021-08-17       665.7100    50.4111          716804.0
2021-08-18       688.9900    49.4700          732574.0
2021-08-19       680.7001        NaN               NaN
```

Which matches Excel (save for the live price on today's date).

EDIT: Adding support for Days and Sort

It is helpful to know that there is not a 1-1 mapping between the options on the Excel BDH call and the underlying Bloomberg API. This document describes the mapping:
https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf Page 92.

So the BDH `Days=A` converts to `Days='ALL_CALENDAR_DAYS'`. But I would suggest that if you don't want weekends, using `Days='NON_TRADING_WEEKDAYS'`

As for Sort, the document says this:  "Some parameters in the BDH() function, such as "Sort", are unavailable in the API schema, as they are unique to the Bloomberg Excel add-ins". ie the Excel addin does the sorting, not the underlying API. Fortunately it is simple to just reverse the received DataFrame if you want to.

Amended code:

```
df = blp.bdh('TSLA US Equity',['PX_LAST','IVOL_Delta','VOLUME_TOTAL_CALL'],datetime(2021,8,1),datetime(2021,8,19),
                 IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL='DELTA_LVL_25',
                 IVOL_MATURITY='MATURITY_90D',
                 IVOL_DELTA_PUT_OR_CALL='IVOL_CALL',
                 Days = 'NON_TRADING_WEEKDAYS').iloc[::-1]
```

With result:

```
           TSLA US Equity                             
                  PX_LAST IVOL_Delta VOLUME_TOTAL_CALL
2021-08-19         673.47    50.1950          461203.0
2021-08-18         688.99    49.4700          732574.0
2021-08-17         665.71    50.4111          716804.0
2021-08-16         686.17    48.3680          639570.0
2021-08-13         717.17    47.3414         1028457.0
2021-08-12         722.25    46.7595          882608.0
2021-08-11         707.82    46.3517          431084.0
2021-08-10         709.99    46.8017          448640.0
2021-08-09         713.76    47.6382          469777.0
2021-08-06         699.10    47.7234          918211.0
2021-08-05         714.63    49.7532          551532.0
2021-08-04         710.92    50.0790          661374.0
2021-08-03         709.74    50.3468          678750.0
2021-08-02         709.67    50.4803         1049494.0
```

Comment: Hi DS_London, it works beautifully, thank you very much!!

I tried to sort by date and also include all dates, so I don't run into trouble with mismatching dates across securities. In excel, I know I can add days=a and Sort=D, but I tried in the code as shown below, but it didn't work, can you help me with that too?

df1 = blp.bdh('GLD US Equity',['PX_LAST','IVOL_Delta','VOLUME_TOTAL_CALL' ...
                 ...
                 IVOL_DELTA_PUT_OR_CALL=['IVOL_CALL','IVOL_PUT'],
                 days='a',
                 Sort='D')

df1

Thanks in advance and have a good weekend!

Comment: @Jørgen I've edited the answer to include Days and Sort.