# How to add options in xbbg API for Bloomberg

Tags: python, wrapper, bloomberg, blpapi

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import arrow
from xbbg import blp

now = arrow.now()
today = str(now.format('YYYYMMDD'))
today_minus_one_year = str(now.shift(days=-365).format('YYYYMMDD'))
start_date = today_minus_one_year

Security = 'AAPL US Equity'
period = 90
Select_interval = 'D'
delta = 25

df_call = blp.bdh([Security],
                  ['PX_LAST','IVOL_Delta','VOLUME_TOTAL_CALL'],
                  start_date=start_date,
                  end_date=today,
                  IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL='DELTA_LVL_'+str(delta),
                  IVOL_MATURITY='MATURITY_'+str(period)+str(Select_interval),
                  IVOL_DELTA_PUT_OR_CALL='IVOL_CALL')
```

which works just fine.

In BDH in Excel, you can add "days=a", and "Sort=D", to get all days and sort in decending order, respectively.

But when I try the code:

```
df_call = blp.bdh([Security],
                  ['PX_LAST','IVOL_Delta','VOLUME_TOTAL_CALL'],
                  start_date=start_date,
                  end_date=today,
                  IVOL_DELTA_LEVEL='DELTA_LVL_'+str(delta),
                  IVOL_MATURITY='MATURITY_'+str(period)+str(Select_interval),
                  IVOL_DELTA_PUT_OR_CALL='IVOL_CALL',
                  days='a',
                  Sort='D')
```

It doesn't work, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I've already answered this as an edit to your previous question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849816/how-to-add-options-to-bloomberg-bdh-query-using-api-in-python

Comment: Hi DS_London, I'm aware thank you, and sorry for asking again, I'm new on stackoverflow, and it got lost for me.. I tried looking up the documentation, which you linked for me, but it was hard for me to translate the "Sort='D'" for me, can you help once again?

Comment: The amended code is at the end of the previous answer. Starting at "As for Sort ...". Do you see this?

Comment: I see DS_London thank you, I didn't realise the .iloc[::-1], reversed the df, thank you!!

Comment: If it's working as you want it, perhaps you could 'accept' (tick) the answer in the previous question?

Comment: It is, thank you very much.